# element not interactable error selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to cklick an article on google news but it showed this error :
element not interactable

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=fr&gl=FR&ceid=FR:fr')
driver.maximize_window()

search_area=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="Ax4B8 ZAGvjd"]')
search_area.click()
search_area.send_keys("josh fire")
sleep(4)
josh=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Source']")
josh.click()
sleep(4)
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='25%'")

sleep(4)

title_list=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="xrnccd"]/article/h3')
title_list[1].click()
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error "*Message: element not interactabl*e" mostly occurs when your element is not clickable or it is not visible yet,

But in your code the `xpath` is not unique. Try the `xpath` like below

```
//a[contains(text(),'Les capteurs de mouvement de Google basés sur un r')]
```

**OR**

```
//a[normalize-space()='Les capteurs de mouvement de Google basés sur un r']
```

Lets us know if this does not work.

Comment: the problem is the element is hidden and it is not clickable there is no solution in selenium i fixed it by using javascript : 

title_list=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="xrnccd"]/article[@class=" MQsxIb xTewfe R7GTQ keNKEd j7vNaf Cc0Z5d EjqUne"]/a[@class="VDXfz"]')
a=title_list[5]
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", a)

Comment: Good to hear that you manage to fix your issue,